# What skills should a functional Blockchain developer have?

Tags: contract-development, dapps, dapp-development

I began my Blockchain development journey a couple months ago by studying to have a firm understanding of what Blockchain is and why is important.

Now that I gained that understanding, im finally going through the Cryptozombies website and before I finish the curriculum, I wanted to have a firm understanding of what skills or capabilities a functional blockchain developer should have. Im asking this because when I took my Intro to Python course, most of the students there left with their certificate of completion but only a handful of us actually grasped the concepts which, btw, were very difficult for me and there were things I wish I knew about Python before I began the course.

So I suppose my question is:

what are employers / blockchain companies looking for in terms of Blockchain development capabilities? What trends should I be looking out for (IE: Layer 2) and how can a nobody like me go from `contract HelloWorld` to DAPP? Should I be looking for a mentor?

Thank you for your continued help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through Cryptozombies is a good start, but it won't make you a good developer. Then you need to practice writing smart contracts, deploying, testing.

- *what are employers / blockchain companies looking for in terms of
  Blockchain development capabilities?*

I would say it depends on the employers, the job, whether you're doing integration, or writing smart contracts.

- *What trends should I be looking out for (IE: Layer 2)*

You need to have a good understanding of the ecosystem, what is crypto, DeFi, blockchain, evm, no-evm, ERCs, protocols, NFT, etc., it will help you understand what is possible, what are the limitations, what already exists or not.

I think you shouldn't follow any trend, you should do what you like, find a good company with a solid project, not just a project that surfs on the hype because most of them will disappear.

- *how can a nobody like me go from contract HelloWorld to DAPP? Should
  I be looking for a mentor?*

Read, test, try, you have a lot of courses online, but I recommend you to read "mastering bitcoin" and "mastering ethereum".
Read famous smart contracts, like Uniswap, Aave, Compound, etc.
You don't need a mentor or someone to rely on, only YOU. Nobody knows everything, you need to keep yourself up-to-date because every month, new protocols appears, new changes, etc.